# SwiftUI menu button is slow to resize when title string changes length

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following `SwiftUI` menu:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    private enum Constants {
        static let arrowIcon = Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
        static let background = Color.blue
        static let buttonFont = Font.system(size: 14.0)
    }


    @State private var menuIndex = 0
    private let menuItems = ["This year", "Last Year"]

    private var menuTitle: String {
        guard menuItems.indices.contains(menuIndex) else { return "" }

        return menuItems[menuIndex]
    }

    // MARK: - Views

    var body: some View {
        makeMenu()
    }

    // MARK: - Buttons

    private func menuItemTapped(title: String) {
        guard let index = menuItems.firstIndex(of: title) else { return }

        menuIndex = index
    }

    // MARK: - Factory

    @ViewBuilder private func makeMenu() -> some View {
        Menu {
            ForEach(menuItems, id: \.self) { title in
                Button(title, action: { menuItemTapped(title: title) })
            }
        } label: {
            Text("\(menuTitle) \(Constants.arrowIcon)")
                .font(Constants.buttonFont)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When a menu item is tapped the index to the title array is updated causing the `Text` title to update. This works as desired however the text is slow to resize to the changes `Last Year...` will briefly show before it resizes correctly.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the size of the label is being set but not being changed. If you're okay with it, setting a `maxWidth` of `.infinity` on the frame of the Label gives you this capability.

```
@ViewBuilder private func makeMenu() -> some View {
        VStack {
            Menu {
                ForEach(menuItems, id: \.self) { title in
                    Button(title, action: { menuItemTapped(title: title) })
                }
            } label: {
                Text("\(menuTitle) \(Constants.arrowIcon)")
                    .font(Constants.buttonFont)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) //--> Add this line
        }
        }
    }
```